# Illegal characters in path error in XML Deserilation

Tags: c#, xml

I have got XML response from my client. I can't deserialize the XML as string, it throws an `Illegal characters in path` error. So now I save the file in temp folder and retrieve that. Is it possible to do the deserialize without saving the XML file first?

```
string xml = Post();

XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));
TextReader reader = new StreamReader(xml); <-- Illegal characters in path error -->
object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
Envelope XmlData = (Envelope)obj;
reader.Close();
```

**Edit 1 -**

```
 XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));
            using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(xml)) <-- StringWriter is Possible here? -->
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, XmlData);
            }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of a `StreamReader`, use a [`StringReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader(v=vs.110).aspx), that takes a [`string` as constructor parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.stringreader(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
```

For writing, use this:

```
string output;
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));
using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(xml)) <-- StringWriter is Possible here? -->
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, XmlData);

    output = writer.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @patrick hofman,. is possible to get the xml as string from object? see my updated question